# Editor for altering the soundtrack to a movie

Tags: linux, linux-mint, video-editing

I have a movie that i'd like to "cuff", ie reverse a few swear words which crop up in it, to make it a bit more family friendly.  Can anyone recommend a good free video editor tool for this?

I don't need to edit the actual visuals at all, just the audio.  I use Audacity already, and had wondered whether it would be better to extract the audio component, edit THAT standalone, then combine it back into the movie.  But i was worried that i'd end up with it being out of sync somehow.

I'd be looking for something where i can just drag over the offending word, and then choose some "reverse audio" function or something.

Any advice welcome.  I'm using Linux Mint Maya 13.2 btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing as you said, extract the audio, use *Audacity* or something similar to "cuff" the audio, then use `ffmpeg` to re-add the audio without re-encoding the video.

Their are multiple methods for censoring words in Audacity.
 - First, the method you specified, you can simply reverse the audio.
 - You can select the audio, mute it with *Generate > Silence*.
 - You can use a TV-style censor beep: you can select the audio and use *Generate > Tone*. Setting *Waveform: **Sine***, *Frequency: **1000***, and *Amplitude: **1*** generally works well, but feel free to experiment.

Comment: Thanks - i've done five minutes worth of the film as a test and it's worked well i think.  The nice thing about "cuffing" is that it's not as jarring as a bleep or an overdub of someone else saying a different word (which you sometimes see in tv versions of movies).  It's pretty quick to do in audacity too.  I tested combining the resulting wav (have just done a couple of minutes worth rather than the whole movie) back into the original film with `ffmpeg` and it's worked well.  I reckon i could do the wav for the whole film in a couple of hours.  That's tonight sorted, better get some beer :)